# Are there mergeable files that can be exported/imported into/out of excel that retains formulas?

Tags: xml, excel, import, version-control, export

I was wondering if there are any files that are mergeable that you can import and export out of excel while retaining formulas.  The goal here is that we want the mergeable file to be the source data, but people can import the data into excel to do changes since excel is more convenient for most people.  The reason for the mergeable file is because we have different teams working on branches of the same files simultaneously, and we need a file that is mergeable(like XML) when we return these branches back to the trunk.  So far the options I've explored all only retain the output of the formulas, or just the formulas themselves.  Any help would be greatly appreciated.

PS. The company has been around for a while, so all data has been in excel and switching to things like Google Sheets would be a huge hassle to everyone.  I'm looking for a solution to this problem, if anyone knows a file type that fits the description or any tools out there that does this would really help!

Best and thank you!

Comment: MS Office together with SharePoint offers version control and work flows. Yet, the various different versions of the documents cannot be merged. Within a certain MS Office file changes can be tracked and reverted or accepted. Yet, this has nothing to do with any other files out there (which might be a fork thereof at some point) and merging different files is not possible. That would be too complicated anyway for a merge because with such a merge tool you could pretty much merge any Excel file with **any** other Excel file: comparing cell by cell and sheet by sheet (incl. code).

Comment: The merge review with all the conflicts (what to approve and what to accept) could easily get out of control. I once created a tool just to compare two file sheet by sheet and cell by cell. Whenever a cell was just moved one cell across the tool would already note it. Changes often ran into the hundreds. And that did not even consider comments to cells or cell formatting or VBA code (and forms) attached to these files. We ended up passing out protected Excel files where only certain parts of the file could be changed. The changes were uploaded to an SQL server and compared there.

Comment: Hi Ralph, thanks for your input!  That tool you created must have been awesome!  And yes I understand merging excel files would be nearly impossible, that's why we are exploring towards the direction of converting to text files.  XML is the closest one we can get, but we can't convert the references over to XML.

Comment: Maybe you can provide some screenshots / samples of what you want to "version control"?

Comment: I'm afraid that I cannot do as it is for commercial use.  But think of it as if I'm looking for a GitHub for excel

Comment: In this case (and if available) I'd suggest the use of SharePoint. You can even build wikis there and those have (very much like wikipedia) version control on board. If that's not an option then I'd actually go with GitHub. You can use Excel to work on the files and then execute the GitHub command line tools in the background to do the comparisons. But that's only my personal opinion and other users here in the community might have better ideas.

Comment: Hey Ralph, thank you so much!  I'll be looking into both SharePoint and GitHub!